# autotools: Fortran module dependencies

Tags: fortran, autotools

I have two sources files:

```
! main.f90
program main
 use foo
 write(*,*) x
end program main

! foo.f90
module foo
 real, parameter :: x = 3.14
end module foo
```

First build is successful. If I now set x = 5 it again builds without errors but the program still prints 3.14. Adding

```
%.o %.mod: %.f90
   $(FC) -c $<
main.o: foo.mod
```

to my Makefile.am makes the problem disappear but this is probably not the correct way to do it.

Some googling reveals that the correct Fortran dependency tracking has been a known problem with Autotools, although I'm not sure if some solution has been found by now. Is there a simple way to fix the above problem?

Comment: I recommend some modern build system like `scons` or `waf`. They can track Fortran module dependencies automatically.

Comment: Well ok, I'll have a look at other build systems. It's just that the above is a very simple example and if that doesn't work properly, then I really don't understand the statement "Automake includes support for Fortran 9x" in the Automake manual.

Comment: See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864763/automake-with-fortran-order-of-file