# automake with fortran: order of file

Tags: fortran, automake

I am facing a small problem when trying to build my code with autotools.
My file structure is:

```
$ tree 
.
|-- configure.ac
|-- Makefile.am
`-- src
    |-- constants.f90
    |-- environment.f90
    |-- init.f90
    |-- main.f90
    `-- util.f90
```

(deleted possibly unnecessary lines)
and my Makefile.am is:

```
#SUBDIRS= help
bin_PROGRAMS = scasr
scasr_SOURCES = \ 
                src/constants.f90  src/environment.f90  src/util.f90 \
                src/init.f90 src/main.f90 
scasr_LDADD = 
EXTRA_DIST= autogen.sh
CLEANFILES =*.mod
```

The problem is src/(*.f90)'s except main.f90 are module. Hence, if I
have to write the makefile by hand, I will have:

```
constants.o : constants.f90 
environment.o : environment.f90 
init.o : init.f90 util.o constants.o 
main.o : main.f90 init.o constants.o environment.o 
util.o : util.f90 constants.o
```

so, for Makefile.am, I have to make a strict order of files in
scasr_SOURCES. i.e.
with the sources as :

```
scasr_SOURCES = \ 
                src/constants.f90  src/environment.f90  src/util.f90 \
                src/init.f90 src/main.f90
```

It compiles fine.
But if I have as:

```
scasr_SOURCES = src/main.f90 \ 
                src/constants.f90  src/environment.f90  src/util.f90 \
                src/init.f90
```

I get error:

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rudra/Programs/ScASR/trunk'
gfortran  -g -O2 -c -o src/main.o src/main.f90
src/main.f90:7.4:

use mget_env
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'mget_env.mod' for reading at (1):
No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

Is there any way out so that make/configure will check the dependency by
itself? Or I **must** keep a strict order?

Comment: What is wrong with the strict order?

Comment: That the project is still under production. Hence, just adding the file name and adding the file name in proper place is much different.

Comment: You could enter the dependencies directly to your `Makefile.am`. So simply put your handwritten Makefile rules (the third code part in your post) in the `Makefile.am`. Automatic dependency tracking is, as far as I know, not (yet) possible. This could change with the addition of submodules, which are defined in Fortran 2008 but not yet implemented in any popular compiler.

Comment: This question is almost two years old. Does anyone know if the Fortran dependency tracking is available in the current versions of Automake?

Comment: @MaliRemorker: Shor answer is NO.
I have made an alternative (in linux system):

`depend depend.mk:
 makedepf90 $(kkr_SOURCES) >depend.mk
@am__include@ @am__quote@depend.mk@am__quote@`

here "kkr" is bin_programs.
Linebreak is not comming properly, but hope, you can understand. makedepf90 is available in most linux distro.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

(Answers in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Stefan wrote:

> You could enter the dependencies directly to your `Makefile.am`. So simply put your handwritten Makefile rules (the third code part in your post) in the `Makefile.am`. Automatic dependency tracking is, as far as I know, not (yet) possible. This could change with the addition of submodules, which are defined in Fortran 2008 but not yet implemented in any popular compiler.

The OP Wrote:

> As per @Stefan's comment, I have added the dependencies in make file, and that solved the problem. I have tested that the order of source code is not important anymore. Since, there is not many stuff in internet available, I am putting the complete procedure here:
>
> 1. create a dependency list (`makedepf90` is a good option)

```
$ makedepf90 src/*.f90 src/constants.o : src/constants.f90 src/environment.o : src/environment.f90 src/init.o : src/init.f90 src/util.o src/constants.o src/main.o : src/main.f90 src/init.o src/constants.o src/environment.o src/util.o : src/util.f90 src/constants.o
```

> 2. Just copy-paste the output of step 1 after the scasr_SOURCES:

`scasr_SOURCES = src/main.f90\ src/constants.f90 src/environment.f90 rc/util.f90  src/init.f90 src/constants.o : src/constants.f90 src/environment.o : src/environment.f90 src/init.o : src/init.f90 src/util.o src/constants.o src/main.o : src/main.f90 src/init.o src/constants.o src/environment.o src/util.o : src/util.f90 src/constants.o`

> NB: I have not tested if it will work if you place it some place else in the makefile. But this is working.