# Autotools and Fortran Modules

Tags: fortran, autotools

I have a problem writing a Makefile.am that will make autotools compile files in the correct order.

My minimal example is some `test.f90` which uses routines from a module `mod.f90`. By hand, I do the following.

```
gfortran -c mod.f90
gfortran -c test.f90
gfortran -o test test.o mod.o
```

This works fine. Now, I have read that autotools does not handle Fortran module dependencies and, according to this post ([automake with fortran: order of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864763/automake-with-fortran-order-of-file)) one should just put the dependencies into Makefile.am by hand.

Mine looks like the following.

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = mod.f90 test.f90 
test: test.f90 mod.o
mod.o: mod.f90
```

While the .mod file for the module is generated each time I run `./configure && make`, it is apparently not generated before all the other files, i.e. I still get the error message `Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘mod.mod’ for reading at (1): No such file or directory`.

Running `./configure && make` twice in a row allows the programme to be compiled but of course this is not really a satisfying solution. Is there some standard way to deal with this? Can I maybe somehow force `mod.o` to be compiled before `test.o`?

Comment: @francescalus Sorry, I should have been more precise. I have edited the question to state that I do ./configure && make.

Comment: What if you specify `test.o: test.f90 mod.o` instead? This is closer to idea of the distinct "two compile plus one link" you start with and the Makefile of the linked question.

Comment: Splendid! This worked!

Comment: Good to hear. I'm inclined to call "should replace test with test.o" indicating a typo. That's a little harsh perhaps, so can you explain why you thought that's the way it should be done so a more comprehensive answer can be made?

Answer (score 2):

The second of these two lines is redundant in light of the first:

> ```
> test_SOURCES = mod.f90 test.f90 
> test: test.f90 mod.o
> ```

This one is unneeded, because Automake (and GNU `make`) already know the information it conveys:

> ```
> mod.o: mod.f90
> ```

That effectively leaves you with just this:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = mod.f90 test.f90
```

That's ok as far as it goes, but it does not express any dependency information related to the `mod.mod` file, so builds may fail. To fix that, you need to add one or more rules that express the additional dependencies and how to satisfy them.

The true dependency is that `test.o` depends on `mod.mod`, and you could write a dependency-only rule expressing that:

```
# INSUFFICIENT
test.o: mod.mod
```

But that leaves you with a problem: `make` doesn't know that `mod.mod` is an output of the compilation of `mod.f90`.  Indeed, situations where multiple targets are created by one run of a recipe are problematic to describe to `make` (and Automake). The Automake manual devotes [one of its lengthier sections](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Multiple-Outputs.html) to this issue.  The most robust possible build system would use an approach such as that section describes to express how to build `mod.o` and `mod.mod`, but that would about triple the size of your `Makefile.am`, and you would need similar extra code for every Fortran module.

You can achieve a fairly good workaround by instead telling Automake that `test.o` depends on `mod.o`:

```
# Better
test.o: mod.o
```

That will yield successful builds from scratch, and under most normal development circumstances, but it does express an incorrect dependency.  As a result, it is susceptible to build breakage by, for example, building the project, then removing `mod.mod` (leaving `mod.o` in place) and updating `test.f90`.  On subsequent builds, `make` will then see that `mod.o` is up to date, so it will do nothing to regenerate the missing `mod.mod`.  A clean build would rescue that, and as a developer, I would probably be prepared to accept that situation for the sake of `Makefile.am` simplicity.

Speaking of a clean build, you should also add `mod.mod` to the list of files that `make clean` should remove:

```
CLEANFILES = mod.mod
```

Overall, then, the final result is:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

bin_PROGRAMS = test

test_SOURCES = mod.f90 test.f90

# A fib -- the real dependency is test.o: mod.mod
test.o: mod.o

CLEANFILES = mod.mod
```